# Create news columns and add key and values from dictionary in new columns for existing csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a csv file like this :

```
id;verbatim
1;je veux manger
2;tu as manger
```

I have my script which return a dictionary like this :

```
dico_phrases = {"['manger']": ['7', '1', '0'], "['être', 'laid']": ['0', '21', '1041']}
```

T would like to add 4 news columns like this :

```
id;verbatim,key,value1,value2,value3
1;je veux manger
2;tu as manger
```

And then add my dictionary in each columns like this :

```
id;verbatim;key,value1,value2,value3
1je veux manger;manger;7;1;0
2;tu as manger;être laid;0;21;1041
```

Below the script which allow me to get my dictionary :

```
with open('output.csv','wb') as f:
      w = csv.writer(f)
      w.writerow(dico_phrases.keys())
      w.writerow(dico_phrases.values())
```

I have this :

```
    ['manger'],"['être', 'laid']"

    "['7', '1', '0']","['0', '21', '1041']"
```

It is not quite I have imagined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this -

```
df = pd.read_csv("input.csv", index_col='id')

dico_phrases = {"['manger']": ['7', '1', '0'], "['être', 'laid']": ['0', '21', '1041']}

df['key'] = [" ".join(eval(x)) for x in dico_phrases.keys()]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame([x for x in dico_phrases.values()], index=df.index))

df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

**Output**:

```
id,verbatim,key,0,1,2
1,je veux manger,manger,7,1,0
2,tu as manger,être laid,0,21,1041
```